# Adjacency list to matrix pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to get through a toy example of building an adjacency matrix from a list, but already I can't quite figure it out. I am thinking in terms of .loc() but I'm not sure how to index correctly.

```
{'nodes':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 'edges':[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), 
                      ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'),('E', 'B'), ('E', 'C')]}
```

I've started to build the matrix with:

```
n = len(graph['nodes'])
adj_matr = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = graph['nodes'], index = graph['edges'])
```

but now I'm not sure how to fill it in. I think there's an easy one liner, maybe with a list comprehension?

Expected output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  1  0  1  0
B  0  0  1  0  1
C  0  0  0  1  0
D  0  0  0  0  1
E  1  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to obtain the adjacency matrix is by using `NetworkX`

```
d = {'nodes':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     'edges':[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), 
                      ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'),('E', 'B'), ('E', 'C')]}
```

It appears that from your adjacency matrix the graph is directed. You can create a directed graph as shown bellow and define its nodes and edges from the dictionary with:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(d['nodes'])
g.add_edges_from(d['edges'])
```

And then you can obtain the adjacency matrix as a dataframe with [`nx.to_pandas_adjacency`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency.html):

```
nx.to_pandas_adjacency(g)

    A    B    C    D    E
A  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
B  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
C  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
D  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
E  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
​
```

Comment: This works - but don't forget to also specify index when constructing the DataFrame  `pd.DataFrame(m.todense(), columns=nx.nodes(g), index=nx.nodes(g))`

Comment: Good thing you brought this up, didn't know at the time of, `to_pandas_adjacency `, updated the post :) @infiniteloop

Answer (score 1):

**for undirected graph**

```
graph = {'nodes': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
         'edges': [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'),
                   ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'), ('E', 'B'), ('E', 'C')]}
n = len(graph['nodes'])
adj_matr = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=graph['nodes'], index=graph['nodes'])
for i in graph['edges']:
    adj_matr.at[i[0], i[1]] = 1
    adj_matr.at[i[1], i[0]] = 1


print(adj_matr)

   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  1  0  1  1
B  1  0  1  0  1
C  0  1  0  1  1
D  1  0  1  0  1
E  1  1  1  1  0
```

**for directed graph:**

```
graph = {'nodes': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
         'edges': [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'),
                   ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'), ('E', 'B'), ('E', 'C')]}
n = len(graph['nodes'])
adj_matr = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=graph['nodes'], index=graph['nodes'])
print(adj_matr)
for i in graph['edges']:
    adj_matr.at[i[0], i[1]] = 1
    # adj_matr.at[i[1], i[0]] = 1

print(adj_matr)

   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  1  0  1  0
B  0  0  1  0  1
C  0  0  0  1  0
D  0  0  0  0  1
E  1  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

For a directed graph you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(graph['edges'], columns=['From', 'To'])
df['Edge'] = 1
adj = df.pivot(index='From', columns='To', values='Edge').fillna(0)
```